# fadeTo() siblings instead of currently hovered div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried plenty of things and nothing appears to be working.
I am not sure if I am using `.siblings()` correctly so I had to remove it and made it simple without the actual thing that I want.

Currently I have made it to be as: fade currently selected/hovered div.

```
$('.recent_each').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, '.5')
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, '1');
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I can set the opacity of `'.5'` to all of the siblings and have the currently hovered div on opacity of `'1'`

I am really confused. Here's html structure tho.

```
echo "
    <div class=\"recent_each\">
        <div class=\"recent_title\">
            <a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='{$info["yt_id"]}'\">
                {$info["yt_name"]}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class=\"recent_thumbnail\">
            <a href=\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='{$info["yt_id"]}'\">
                <img src=\"{$info["thumb"]}\" alt=\"Recently Converted Thumbnail\">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
";
```

*As of CSS, there's no opacity at all set in there.*

Comment: I don't see any siblings in your HTML? Do you have multiple divs with class `recent_each`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, yes there are 5 wrapped within <div class="recent_wrap" />

Comment: why do you use stop()?

Comment: @MichaelAguilar to prevent that fadeTo animation when someone is mad and hover over all the divs like a maniac. So it looks buggy. This way it is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.siblings`:

```
$('.recent_each').hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.recent_each').stop().fadeTo(300, '.5')
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings('.recent_each').stop().fadeTo(300, '1');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this +1. Works so smooth and the effect is just as the one that I was trying to accomplish. Apparently I don't know to use .siblings()